# eclipse android common xml editor stops rendering text correctly (randomly)

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-7-x64, android-xml

So I have (and have had) this problem when editing Android XML in eclipse. I've tried different versions of eclipse and different Android SDK's and entire re-downloads and whatnot but am still presented with this error. When editing an XML in eclipse, in a somewhat unpredictable manner, the text will randomly visibly misalign itself. The text itself is still in the same place, but it's rendered to be in different places. The problem doesn't go away unless I restart eclipse altogether.

The three pictures below are all of the exact same file without ANY modifications.

This picture is how it looks when I select All (ctrl+A)

[image: How it looks when I select all (ctrl+A)]

This picture is how it looks when I deselect

[image: How it looks when I unselect text]

And this last one is how it looks when I restart eclipse. Note that this is the proper look and it should be like this all of the time.

[image: How it looks when I restart eclipse (this is how it's supposed to look)]

I've been experiencing these problems for a very long time and it's very irritating. I've also reinstalled Windows-7 x64 many times and the problem has never gone away. Please help?

Comment: I have the same probleme (with Eclipse 3.7 & 4.2) but no solution,sry. Little tip: I only close and reopen the tab in question, and the display becomes ok (more user friendly than restart Eclipse)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing now. Still disappointing. Gonna have to make the switch to linux soon.

Comment: any Update? Facing the same problem. Did you file a bug Report?

Comment: @saberrider - I haven't filed it, but there's one filed here https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=375421

Comment: This is fixed in ADT Plugin v21.

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem formating the document:
Right click on the editor window, from the menu select Source -> format
or, in short: Ctrl+Shift+F

Answer (score 0):

Closing and opening the tabs wasn't working for me. But something that did get it to stop was to go into preferences, and under XML/XML Files/Editor and choose clear blank lines and applied.

I don't know if it will continue to happen though.

Comment: does this remove the issue altogether or has it just removed it for the currently opened eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing similar issues too, when you select a line in xml source view,
the lines keeps on jumping up and down, some times it changes to previous line.
But if you open the xml in some non android xml editor then it works fine.
Not able to use android graphical editor.